# C++ template deduction for pointer variables?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make this code compile:

```
        object<128> Object;
        object *ObjectPointer = &Object;
```

But it won't because ObjectPointer needs template arguments too. I don't like that because I think it's redundant. Is there a way to avoid specifying the template arguments?

Edit: without using `auto`. I like seeing the exact type.

Comment: `auto ObjectPointer = &Object;` (Also, it's not redundant. An `object<128>*` in general cannot point to an `object<64>`, unless inheritance.)

Comment: @lorro thanks for the answer but I don't want to use auto. Looks like it's generally impossible without auto though.

Comment: Your problem is that `object` is not a type but a template.  instantiating `object<FOO>` and `object<BAR>` creates two separate and distinct types.  That means there is no  `object*` that you can have.  You must specify you have an `object<some_value>*`.

Comment: A pointer type still needs to know the size of the object it is pointing to.  Since the template arg can affect the size of the type, the pointer *must* know the relevant template args.

Comment: _"without using `auto`. I like seeing the exact type."_ - then why is writing `object<128>*` a problem? It _is_ the exact type, while `object*` is not.

Comment: Not wanting to use `auto` for the exact problem it solves sounds off.

Comment: Consider: `object<128> o1; object<64> o2; object *op1 = &o1; object *op2 = &o2;`. I think it'd be somewhat confusing at this point that `op1` and `op2` are potentially unrelated.

Comment: @NathanOliver OP wants CTAD. `object ObjectCopy = Object;` works perfectly well.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. CTAD? https://www.gov.uk/guidance/ctad-chlamydia-surveillance-system?. Oh I see - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction :)

Comment: *Every instance of a template is a completely different class*. `object<128>` is a *completely unrelated class* to `object<127>`. So the usual rules apply - a base class pointer can point to a derived class, and if there's no base/derived class going on, then it can't.

Comment: @MikeVine CTAD doesn't work for pointers, only classes.